# How to toggle div in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have next HTML code with `ng-click`:

```
<div id="bl" ng-click="toggleBlock('photos')"></div>

<div class="item" ng-show="toggle == 'photos'"></div>
```

**Angular JS:**

```
$scope.toggleBlock = function (type) {
   $scope.toggle = type;
}
```

By default block `#bl` is hidden.
When I do click the block `.item` is opened. But when I click again, block is not hidden.

How I can do toggle element?

Also I tried:

**HTML:**

```
ng-click="toggleBlock('photos')"
<div ng-show="toggle.photos"></div>
```

**Angular JS:**

```
 $scope.toggle = {
    'photos' : false
 };

 $scope.toggleBlock = function (type) {
    $scope.toggle.type = ($scope.toggle.type) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: You have to toggle div on type or you have to toggle only one div?

Answer (score 0):

You can update a boolean in your controller to `true` or `false`
and then bind it to the `ng-show` of the element you are going to toggle.

**this is how your HTML will look like:**

```
<div id="bl" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="toggleBlock()"></div>
<div class=" btn btn-info" ng-show="visible==true"></div>
```

**and this is what inside your controller:**

```
$scope.toggleBlock=function() {
    $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
}
```

Comment: Problem is that I have some toogleBlock on page. See please my update question, sexond solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.toggleBlock = function (type) {
   $scope.toggle = ($scope.toggle === type) ? false : type;
}
```

long version:

```
if($scope.toggle === type){ // your toggle already set to type
    $scope.toggle = ''; // (or false) reset it's value, so ng-show="toggle == 'photos'" will fail and hide the element
}
else{ // $scope.toggle is not set or has another value, so we can assing type to it
    $scope.toggle = type;
}
```

it's only useful if you have multiple named blocks:

`<div class="item" ng-show="toggle == 'photos'"></div>`

`<div class="item" ng-show="toggle == 'albums'"></div>`

and multiple named toggles, if you are working with a sigle div of photos - consider using boolean value as others suggest

Comment: May be you mean: `false : true;` ?

Answer (score 0):

The directive ng-show will evaluate displayPhotos and show it depending on displayPhotos ( true or false )

and the toggleBlock will let you switch true or false displayPhotos.

```
<div id="bl" ng-click="toggleBlock()"></div>

<div class="item" ng-show="displayPhotos"></div>
```

In your controller.js :

```
$scope.displayPhotos = false;

$scope.toggleBlock = function () {
 $scope.displayPhotos = !$scope.displayPhotos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check might be you want this -

http://plnkr.co/edit/5vcJEZQri5TGQDuH51Sr?p=preview

In controller -

```
 $scope.toggle = false;
 $scope.toggleBlock =function () {
   $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="bl" ng-click="toggleBlock()">Click me to see photo div: Photo</div>

 <div class="item" ng-show="toggle">
   Photo div
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes, but I have some toogleBlock in page

Comment: Means you have multiple div of different type and you want to to show base on their type right?

Answer (score 0):

At the very least your toggling function should be

```js
$scope.toggleBlock = function (type) {
    $scope.toggle[type] = !$scope.toggle[type];
}
```